# ParallelCollectionRDD.reducebykey(_-_) is not giving correct result

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get value for below reduceByKey function on RDD, however it is not giving the correct result.

```
scala> val test =sc.parallelize(( (1 to 5).map(x=>("key",x)))).reduceByKey(_-_).collect
res62: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((key,-3))
```

Then I tried doing following calculation

```
scala> List (1,2,3,4,5).reduce(_-_)
res65: Int = -13
```

Is this happening because there is no guaranty of order in RDD operations and so reduce function is getting applied in any order whereas in case of List order is guaranteed so reduce function is behaving correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug but an expected behavior. If you open the doc for [reduceByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) you may see (emphasis is mine):

> Merge the values for each key using an **associative and commutative** reduce function.

Those two properties are essential for parallelization:

- [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) means that `(a ∗ b) ∗ c = a ∗ (b ∗ c)` (where `∗` is operation)
- [Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) means `a ∗ b = b ∗ a`

Subtraction is neither associative nor commutative. Thus the result of `reduceByKey` is undefined.

Actually even Scala standard library [GenTraversable.reduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/GenTraversable.html) says (again emphasis is mine)

> Reduces the elements of this collection or iterator using the specified **associative** binary operator.
>
> The **order** in which operations are performed on elements **is unspecified and may be nondeterministic**.

So the claim "*whereas in case of List order is guaranteed so reduce function is behaving correctly*" is also false. The order on `List` is an implementation details and theoretically might be changed at any time (although in practice this is not likely to happen because of performance considerations).

Just in case you wonder how -3 can be achieved, here is one possible explanation:

```
(-1 - -2 - -3) - (-4 - -5)
```

Comment: So it is because of associative and commutative law which subtract operation is not compliant.

Comment: @ChandramohanSawant Almost. I'd say that it is because the result is undefined if the operation does not conform to the laws (or rather can be any of a quite a few choices). In practice if you think about how Spark is implemented inside, you can clearly see that they can't at the same time do parallel processing and preserve the sequential logic. Since Spark is used for the  parallelization, the conforming to the sequeential logic was given up.